# Android dialog fragment, with tabs or flipper

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-dialogfragment

I'd like to create a DialogFragment that has a set of options and when a specific option is click the dialog changes and displays a new set of options (sub options of the category previously chosen).

Is it possible to create a DialogFragment with that kind of interface?